# Woocommerce: display parent category (is any) instead of current category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

Creating a custom theme, I have to alter the way WooCommerce behaves when displaying a product category.

The default behavior is to display subcategories and/or products for user-selected category. For example subcategories and/or products for *sub-sub-category_a* when requesting `https://wordpress_site/product-category/category_a/sub-category_a/sub-sub-category_a/`

What I want to achieve is to either:

- keep the default behavior if current category has no parent (ie `https://wordpress_site/product-category/category_a`)
- alter the default behavior if current category has a parent (`https://wordpress_site/product-category/category_a/sub-category_a/sub-sub-category_a/`) and instead display the products for the parent category *sub-category_a* instead of the products for the current category *sub-sub-category_a*

In my opinion, I have to alter the $wp_query when archive-product.php template is called, but I have no clue how to achieve this the right way.
Could you please help me?

To answer the question "why?", the aim is top add a select box with the children categories on top of the page and dynamically filter the product list client side to either only show products for the selected category or all the products if none or an "all categories" option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, if a product category has a parent, you want to retrieve all products for the parent category.

To achieve this you need to edit the query, along these lines:

```
function prefix_get_parent_category_products( $query ){

    // check we're in the right place and the category has a parent
    if( $query->is_tax('product_cat') && !empty($query->query_vars['post_parent']) ){

        // edit the tax query to include the parent category
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $query->query_vars['post_parent'],
            'include_children' => true
        )
    }
    return;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_get_parent_category_products' );
```

Note, I've not tested this function so you may need to adapt to your needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No. I want to display parent category (and all its products and products for its sub-category) instead of requested category if the requested category has a parent.

Comment: @MaxAuray Apologies - I clearly misunderstood. However, using the same approach it should be possible to achieve what you need. I'll edit my answer when I get a minute...

Comment: @MaxAuray I've updated my answer - hopefully it's more helpful this time! The key points are that you need to modify the query using `pre_get_posts` and then alter the tax query to use the parent category's `term_id`